# How to replace all shared_ptr<T>(new_w<T>) with make_shared<T>()?

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2010, replace

How to replace regexp like `shared_ptr<\w+\>\(new_w<\w+\>\(\)\)` with `make_shared<$1>()` where `$1` will be first `\w+` (generally replace all `shared_ptr<T>(new_w<T>())` with `make_shared<T>()`)?

Answer (score 0):

Add a capturing group:

```
shared_ptr<(\w+)\>\(new_w<\w+\>\(\)\)
```